# whitespace after heading when followed by \begin{tikzpicture}

Tags: tikz-styles

The first chapter section of a book to use tikz ended up placing a great deal of whitespace after the section heading.  I've tried `\vspace` adjustments, but it changes all the vspaces between `\begin` & `\end` tikz.  The goal here is to produce three blank graphs below the question.  ALSO, placing the vertical axis titles above (instead of to the right) causes those vertical axes to be misaligned because the entire tikz picture gets nudged over to account for the differing label lengths.  Is there a way to compensate for this?

HERE'S THE CODE...

```
\chapter[1D Kinematics]{One Dimensional Kinematics}
\newpage
\section{Graph Matching 1}
```

Draw a curve (sometimes "curves" are straight) on each graph below representing the motion of a person walking steadily towards a motion detector, stopping, and then walking steadily away from the detector at a slower rate.

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [thin, gray, <->] (0,-3) -- (0,3)      % draw y-axis line
       node [right, black] {$position$};              % add label for y-axis
    \draw [thin, gray, <->] (-1,0) -- (10,0)      % draw x-axis line
        node [right, black] {$time$};              % add label for x-axis
 \end{tikzpicture}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [thin, gray, <->] (0,-3) -- (0,3)      % draw y-axis line
       node [right, black] {$velocity$};              % add label for y-axis
    \draw [thin, gray, <->] (-1,0) -- (10,0)      % draw x-axis line
        node [right, black] {$time$};              % add label for x-axis
 \end{tikzpicture}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [thin, gray, <->] (0,-3) -- (0,3)      % draw y-axis line
        node [right, black] {$acceleration$};              % add label for y-axis
    \draw [thin, gray, <->] (-1,0) -- (10,0)      % draw x-axis line
        node [right, black] {$time$};              % add label for x-axis
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: With your given code snippets it is hard to reproduce your problem.  Please create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows your problem (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using three separate `tikzpicture`s (one for each graph), you can use one `tikzpicture` for all the three graphs and scopes with an appropriate vertical shifting; this will also automatically solve the alignment problem:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\chapter[1D Kinematics]{One Dimensional Kinematics}
\newpage
\section{Graph Matching 1}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=.89]
    \draw [thin, gray, <->] (0,-3) -- (0,3)      % draw y-axis line
       node [above, black] {$position$};              % add label for y-axis
    \draw [thin, gray, <->] (-1,0) -- (10,0)      % draw x-axis line
        node [right, black] {$time$};              % add label for x-axis
\begin{scope}[yshift=-7cm]
    \draw [thin, gray, <->] (0,-3) -- (0,3)      % draw y-axis line
       node [above, black] {$velocity$};              % add label for y-axis
    \draw [thin, gray, <->] (-1,0) -- (10,0)      % draw x-axis line
        node [right, black] {$time$};              % add label for x-axis
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-14cm]
    \draw [thin, gray, <->] (0,-3) -- (0,3)      % draw y-axis line
        node [above, black] {$acceleration$};              % add label for y-axis
    \draw [thin, gray, <->] (-1,0) -- (10,0)      % draw x-axis line
        node [right, black] {$time$};              % add label for x-axis
\end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that I used `yscale=.89` to prevent an overfull vbox (otherwise, the graphs would have a height too long for the current available vertical space in the page); depending on your current page layout settings you might need to adjust the value used.

If you are also planning to plot some functions, I would suggest you to consider using [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) (internally uses TikZ); a simple example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
every axis/.append style={
  axis lines=middle,
  enlargelimits=true,
  axis line style={<->}
},
ymin=-3,
ymax=3,
xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty,
xlabel=time,
domain=0:1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=.8]
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[blue] {2};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[yshift=-7cm]
  \addplot[green] {-2};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[yshift=-14cm]
  \addplot[red] {1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For further details, please refer to the comprehensive package documentation.

Comment: ThanX ... that works perfectly when I change yscale to 0.79.  At yscale = 0.89, it pushed the paragraph following the heading to the bottom of that page and the graphs to the next.  And now I have my homework trying to figure out how all of these components are related.

Comment: @Clark You're welcome! Don't forget, after a sensible wait, that you can accept (different from up-vote) the answer that best solved your problem by using the checkmark to the left of the answer. In case of doubt, please see [`How do you accept an answer?`](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: @Clark I've updated my answer with some information that you could find useful.